# How can I solve this difference equation, if $p=q$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms, homogeneous-equation, differential-algebra

I'm trying to solve the difference equation 
$$
pE_{k+1} - E_{k} + qE_{k-1} = -1
$$
given the boundary conditions $E_{0} = 0, \; E_{a} = 0$, if $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$

To attempt this, I first found and solved the characteristic polynomial, as follows:
$$
p \lambda^{2} - \lambda + q = 0 \\
\iff (p \lambda - q)(\lambda - 1) \\
\iff \lambda_{1} = \frac{q}{p}, \; \lambda_{2} = 1
$$

But since we know that $p=q$, we know that $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = 1$. Thus, the general solution to the homogeneous difference equation would be
$$
E_{k} = Ak + B
$$

I have then found that
$$
E_{k} = \frac{k}{p-q}
$$
is a particular integral for this equation, so we no that the solution to the inhomogeneous equation would be
$$
E_{k} = Ak + B + \frac{k}{p-q}
$$

Finally, the boundary conditions $E_{0} = 0, \; E_{a} = 0$ can be used to find the constants $A$ and $B$, as follows:
$$
E_{0} = A(0) + B + \frac{0}{p-q} = B = 0
$$

and

$$
E_{a} = A(a) + \frac{a}{p-q} = 0 \Rightarrow A = -\frac{1}{p-q}
$$

Thus, our exact solution would be
$$
E_{k} = Ak + B + \frac{k}{p-q} = -\frac{k}{p-q} + \frac{k}{p-q} = 0
$$

Why has my final solution come out as $E_{k}=0$?

Comment: How your particular integral is $E_K=\frac{k}{p-q}$ as $p=q$ ?

Comment: Particular Solution = General Solution + Particular Integral

Comment: I mean the particular integral

Comment: Using a trial PI of the form $ck$ for some constant $c$ and subbing it into the original difference equation to find the value of the constant $c$ in terms of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that $p=q=0.5$.

Comment: Did you understand how the difference equation is solved ? $E_k$=\frac{k}{p-q}$ is not a particular integral. It is even not defined, because of the denominator.

Comment: Mean exit time of simple random walk from interval (0,a)... This could be mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the RHS is $-1.1^k$, this means that you should search for particular integral of the form $ck^2$, where the square is because $\lambda =1$ is a double root of the characteristic equation.
Then, plugging it in the difference equation:
$$\frac{1}{2}c(k+1)^2-ck^2+\frac{1}{2}(k-1)^2=-1$$
$$c=-1$$.
So your general solution is $E_k=Ak+B-k^2$. From the initial conditions $E_0=E_a=0$:
$$0=B$$
$$0=Aa+B-a^2\Rightarrow Aa-a^2=0\Rightarrow a(A-a)=0 \Rightarrow A=a\Rightarrow E_k=ak-k^2$$

Comment: $E_a=0$ gives $A=a$ and $E_k=k(a-k)$.

Comment: @LutzL I thought, it is not $a$ but $1$, i.e $E_0=E_1=0$ as initial conditions. I will correct it.